# Will google apps filter spam for dual delivery

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email-filter

We're transferring to google apps for business and we're going to enable Dual Delivery with their server as primary MX target.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/178267

We're wondering if google will apply their spam filter before routing the mail to our server.

Comment: We cannot predict how Google's spam filter will do exactly we are not Google.  Unless the filter has a reason to believe its spam ( based on previous reports ) its unlikely it will be flagged as spam.  Only way to know is to test it.

Comment: Let's say we mark one of our known addresses as spam. would it bother to forward it? Meanwhile I'm indeed waiting for a reply from google directly, And we'll be testing but I figured why not throw multiple lines?

Comment: You would have to contact Google to determine that.  If you mark an an email as spam, Google will use that information, to determine what email you have decided is spam.